# &nbsp; not working with javascript if condition

Tags: javascript

I am having javascript problem in my VF page so I am posting this question here.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <input id="xyz" value="&nbsp;"/>
    <script>
        alert( document.getElementById('xyz').value);
        var x = document.getElementById('xyz').value;
        if(  x == '&nbsp;' )
           alert(1)
        else
           alert(2);
    </script>
</html>
```

The input field xyz is having the value as `&nbsp;` I am checking the  value in javascript but the if condition never evaluates to true. What could be the problem?  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mailtoshebin/NDBY3/)

Comment: Why don't you do `alert(x)` and find out?

Comment: tested and returns  space

Answer (score 4):

The static `String.fromCharCode()` method returns a string created by using the specified sequence of Unicode values.

For the non-breaking space, you can use `String.fromCharCode(160)`

```
  if(  x ==String.fromCharCode(160))
      alert(1)
   else
       alert(2);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/36eyp/

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode

HTML:

```
 <span id="xyz" >&nbsp;</span>
```

Javascript:

```
    alert( document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML);
    var x = document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML;
    if(  x == '&nbsp;' )
       alert(1)
    else
       alert(2);
```

http://www.adamkoch.com/2009/07/25/white-space-and-character-160/

Comment: if I use <span id="xyz"  >&nbsp;</span> and  var x = document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML; in javascript it is not working can you please help me?

Comment: Updated my answer, please check

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(160)` worked for me. `if(str == ' ')` was not working in if condition, neither did trim(); but `if(str == String.fromCharCode(160))` worked.

Answer (score 2):

Use the UNICODE representation of the `&nbsp;` HTML entity, `\u00a0`:

```
if (x == "\u00a0")
    alert(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`&nbsp;` will not the one obtained in function :

```
var x = document.getElementById('xyz').value;
if(  x == '\xa0' ){
    alert(1)
}else{
    alert(2);
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NDBY3/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex as well. Probably not the best solution, but it works.

```
alert( document.getElementById('xyz').value)
var x = document.getElementById('xyz').value
if(/^\s$/.test(x))
    alert(1)
else
    alert(2)
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfs9u/1/)

Answer (score -3):

`&nbsp;` is the entity used to represent a non-breaking space. It is essentially a standard space, the primary difference being that a browser should not break (or wrap) a line of text at the point that this `&nbsp;` occupies.

Comment: Downvoted because OP stated in post and in comments that he needed to know why his test to match &nbsp wasn't working, indicating he already knows what  `&nbsp;` is. Providing a sparse definition doesn't add to the conversation, nor help solve the OP's question. Reading the question more thoroughly next time will help avoid posting filler answers like this.